# How to convert unsigned char* to unsigned long long int?

Tags: c, type-conversion, built-in, unsigned-char, unsigned-long-long-int

Does anyone know of a library that provides a function that performs this logic or perhaps a method to perform this logic?

I'm trying to convert:

```
unsigned char test[] = "\x00\x00\x56\x4b\x7c\x8a\xc5\xde";
```

to:

```
94882212005342 / 0x0000564b7c8ac5de
```

I'm aware I could loop over each individual byte in `test` and utilize `sprintf` to convert each byte to string and concatenate them into a buffer with `strcat` and convert the buffer string to `unsigned long long` via `strtoull`. However I'm looking for something more comprehensive and simple. Is there such a way?

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is not clear what you want. From the question I quess you want to get a unsigned long long from the byte array. But the part about `sprintf` does not fit at all.

Comment: I edited and gave more detail.

Comment: Is your array always exactly 9 bytes long?

Comment: yes 8 + null byte.

Comment: 64 bit memory address.

Comment: Is the output representing a string?

Comment: As your array is not a valid string, I would suggest, not to use string notation. Instead you might use `unsigned char test[8] = {000, 0x00, 0x56, 0x4b, 0x7c, 0x8a, 0xc5, 0xde}`

Comment: Why is your 64 bit memory address a string to begin with? Why not an unsigned long? It already has the required bytes, presumably in the right order, and isn't even a valid string...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just maths.

```
unsigned char test[] = "\x00\x00\x56\x4b\x7c\x8a\xc5\xde";
unsigned long long num = 
     (unsigned long long)test[0] << 56 |
     (unsigned long long)test[1] << 48 |
     (unsigned long long)test[2] << 40 |
     (unsigned long long)test[3] << 32 |
     (unsigned long long)test[4] << 24 |
     (unsigned long long)test[5] << 16 |
     (unsigned long long)test[6] <<  8 |
     (unsigned long long)test[7] <<  0;
```

Remember to cast to type wide enough before shifting.

You have 8 values:

```
 { 0x00, 0x00, 0x56, 0x4b, 0x7c, 0x8a, 0xc5, 0xde }
```

which in the decimal is:

```
 0 0 86 75 124 138 197 222
```

and you want to have:

```
 94882212005342
```

which is:

```
  94882212005342 = 0*2^56 + 0*2^48 + 86*2^40 + 75*2^32 + 124*2^24 + 138*2^16 + 197*2^8 +  222*2^0
```

It's a mathematical operation. You could write ex `test[0] * 72057594037927936ull` but that's less readable then `test[0] << 56`.

Comment: Could you give a bit of explanation as to what is happening here?

Comment: Take the first byte from `test`. But it at the 56 bit the output number. Take the second byte from `test`. But it at the 48 bit position in the output number. etc.

Comment: Is it possible to condense this with a loop perhaps?

Comment: See https://github.com/biiont/gpsd/blob/master/bits.h#L45

Comment: @KamilCuk line 64, surely? `num = getbeu64(test, 0);`.

Comment: The link is not meant to be to a specific line - rather to the whole library.

Comment: How would it be possible to do this with a 7-byte `unsigned char` array (6 + null-byte).

Answer (score 1):

I have done something very similar with the use of memmove or memcpy functions https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_memmove.htm

```
    long long int var = 0; 
    memmove( &var, test, sizeof(var) );
```

Make sure to use the correct byte order of your system.

Comment: This will fail on little-endian systems. (or big endian, I always mix them).

Comment: Aren't 90% of systems little-endian? Interesting point, it is very elegant though.

Comment: Sure, if you are looking for a general solution I totally agree.with @KamilCuk

Comment: @KamilCuk, it may be exactly what OP was asking for. OP may have been given implementation-defined `char[]` represetation of `ull` on OP's platfrom. This solution may be the correct one.

Comment: @tstanisl That violates the strict aliasing rule

Comment: Is there a similar method to do this in reverse-order `unsigned long long int` to `unsigned char*`?

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, you can just simply do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned char test[] = "\x00\x00\x56\x4b\x7c\x8a\xc5\xde";
    uint64_t val=0;
    for(size_t i=0; i<8; i++)
      val |= (uint64_t)test[i] << (7-i)*8;
    printf("%" PRIu64 " %" PRIX64, val, val);
}
```

Comment: And optionally: `#include <limits.h> _Static_assert(CHAR_BITS==8, "Get a useful computer instead of that crap.");` in case you need to ward off language lawyers, DSP programmers from the 1980s or other such creatures.

Answer (score -1):

A fun BUT NOT RECOMMENDED way of doing this. If you want a proper solution, look at [KamilCuk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66600637/6699433)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Reverse an 8-byte array  
void rev(unsigned char *s) {
    unsigned char *end = s + 7; // Evil hard coded value

    while(s<end) {
        unsigned char tmp = *s;
        *s = *end;
        *end = tmp;
        s++;
        end--;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    unsigned char test[] = "\x00\x00\x56\x4b\x7c\x8a\xc5\xde";
    rev(test);                // Reverse the array
    long l;
    memcpy(&l, test, sizeof test);
    printf("%zx\n", l);
}
```

Note that the standard does not dictate the byte order. This is what works on MY machine. It will be the same on most machines, but if portability to other architectures is important to you. Don't even consider this.

However, since you're saying that the value is an address, I'd recommend using `uintptr_t` instead of `long`.