# How to convert unsigned long long int into unsigned char*?

Tags: c, type-conversion, 64-bit, unsigned-char, unsigned-long-long-int

Say for instance I have this `unsigned long long int`:

```
unsigned long long int test_int = 0xcfffedefcfffeded; // 14987959699154922989
```

How could I convert `test_int` into the following `unsigned char*` array:

```
unsigned char test_char[] = "\xcf\xff\xed\xef\xcf\xff\xed\xed";
```

Similar to this question I asked:
[How to convert unsigned char* to unsigned long long int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66600509/how-to-convert-unsigned-char-to-unsigned-long-long-int/66601019#66601019)
The only exception is being in reverse.

Comment: What have you tried? What research did you do? Is there really a need for this question? Doesn't the last question hint you how to do it? I even linked a library that implements that conversion - have you studied it? Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784263/converting-an-int-into-a-4-byte-char-array-c .

Comment: I only glanced at it after learning your example worked, I'll re-read it.

Comment: Forgive me but what line would that be located on @ https://github.com/biiont/gpsd/blob/master/bits.h#L45 ?

Comment: Note: `"\xcf\xff\xed\xef\xcf\xff\xed\xed"` is a `char` array of _9_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inline conversion (endian-indpendent) with bit shifts

```
char test_char[8];
test_char[0] = (char)(unsigned char)(test_int >> 56);
test_char[1] = (char)(unsigned char)(test_int >> 48);
test_char[2] = (char)(unsigned char)(test_int >> 40);
test_char[3] = (char)(unsigned char)(test_int >> 32);
test_char[4] = (char)(unsigned char)(test_int >> 24);
test_char[5] = (char)(unsigned char)(test_int >> 16);
test_char[6] = (char)(unsigned char)(test_int >> 8);
test_char[7] = (char)(unsigned char)(test_int);
```

Bonus: we don't need to talk about alignment or endianness. This just works.

As has been pointed out in the comments, `test_char` in the question has a trailing null terminator, which we can also do by setting `char test_char[9];` and `test_char[8] = 0;`; however when this question comes up in practice, the real example rarely has  a terminating null nor would it make sense because of nulls in the middle.

Commentary: I wish there was a standard `htonq` for this, but there isn't.

Comment: Would this work for any `unsigned char*` regardless of it's values?

Comment: @mehmed_ali343: Yup.

Comment: How would it be possible to do this with a 7-byte `unsigned char` array (6 + null-byte).

Comment: @mehmed_ali343: You can't. `sizeof(unsigned long long) == 8`